# Error: Cannot use GraphQLSchema "[object GraphQLSchema]" from another module or realm

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, graphql, graphql-js

Given the following code:

```
import { graphql } from 'graphql'
import graphqlTools from 'graphql-tools'

const { makeExecutableSchema } = graphqlTools

const typeDefs = `
type Query {
   as: [A]
}

type A {
   x: Int,
   y: Int
}
`
const schema = makeExecutableSchema ({ typeDefs })

graphql(schema, '{ as { x, y } }').then(console.log)
```

I get this error:

> Error: Cannot use GraphQLSchema "[object GraphQLSchema]" from another
>   module or realm.
>
> Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the
>   node_modules directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the
>   dependencies of other relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure
>   only one version is installed.

What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because `graphql-tools` module imports `graphql` from its CommonJS module, while my code does it from the ES module. That is, each object in my own module comes from the ES module, while `graph-tool`'s not.

### Solution

It's as easy as importing anything from `graphql` importing the CommonJS module, and both objects from `graphql` and `graphql-tools` will be able to talk each together:

```
import graphql_ from 'graphql/index.js'
import graphqlTools from 'graphql-tools'

const { graphql } = graphql_
const { makeExecutableSchema } = graphqlTools

const typeDefs = `
type Query {
   as: [A]
}

type A {
   x: Int,
   y: Int
}
`
const schema = makeExecutableSchema ({ typeDefs })

graphql(schema, '{ as { x, y } }').then(console.log)
```

Comment: I have filed an issue with graphql-tools trying to sort that but while your patch works we cannot find source of issue.. Any ideas? still does it in latest versions

Comment: @cyberwombat Would you mind sharing the issue?

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins turns out that `graphql-tools` fixed that issue a while back so was not actually the culprit for me. My issue was that yarn was not upgrading `graphql-tools` fully - it oddly would tell me it upgraded but kept old files.  A full `node_modules` delete/install with latest `graphql-tools` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 16):

This situation may also occur when the version of the `graphql` module you have installed is different from the version installed and used by `graphql-tools`.

I have found you can correct this by either:

1. Changing the version of `graphql` in your project's `package.json` file  to match exactly what `graphql-tools` depends on in its `package.json` file.
2. Removing `graphql` as a dependency and just installing `graphql-tools`. Then you will automatically receive whatever `graphql` module version that `graphql-tools` installs (as long as you don't depend on any other packages that install another, conflicting version).

In other cases you might have the correct version, but it may be installed multiple times. You can use `npm ls graphql` to see all the installed versions. Try running `npm dedupe` to remove duplicate installations.

Comment: This worked for me, the `ls` command gave me context, but the `dedupe` cleaned it up.

Answer (score 6):

My problem was both `.js` an `.mjs` graphql files are resolved due to wrong webpack configuration.

***Root cause:***

From `TypeMapper.mjs` file in `graphql-compose`, import statement does not have file extension and that was a failure on webpack bundle. In order to solve it, I required to add `fullySpecified:false` into the webpack config.

```js
{
  test: /\.m?js/,
  include: /node_modules/,
  type: "javascript/auto",
  resolve: {
    fullySpecified: false
  }
}
```

And I also modified resolve statement like

```js
resolve: {
  extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".mjs"] // that was the actual problem
}
```

Since `fullySpecified` config has been set to `false`, webpack was trying to resolve files without extension respect to the order of `resolve.extentions` config. Due to the wrong order in that config, `graphql` files with `.js` ext were been resolving although all other files were using `.mjs` one.

***Solution:***

Simply re-order `resolve.extensions` config as

```js
resolve: {
  extensions: [".ts", ".mjs", ".js"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I added the [`webpack-node-externals`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) library to the webpack configuration, and I was able to run my bundled application.

```
    externalsPresets: { node: true },
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
```

I am using webpack version 5.*

Also I am using `yarn` package manager, so I added `resolutions` in my `package.json`

```
  "resolutions": {
    "graphql": "^15.3.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was solved by downgrading some packages like this:

`"apollo": "^2.33.4", "graphql": "^15.5.0",`

I also deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and installed packages with yarn instead of npm.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact error when my .npmrc did not have proper entries such as username and password. We are using jFrog to normalise package installation. .npmrc should be located at root with proper entries.
ex: .npmrc file which works

```
@<company-name>:registry=<registry-url>
//<artifactory-name>:_password=${PASSWORD}
//<artifactory-name>:username=${JFROG_USERNAME}
//<artifactory-name>:email=${YOUR_EMAIL}
//<artifactory-name>:always-auth=true
```